# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_sqlalchemy

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy

I am getting this error when i try to run:

```
flask db upgrade
```

> from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_sqlalchemy'

I verified that flask-sqlalchemy is already installed:

> Requirement already satisfied: flask-sqlalchemy in ./venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (2.4.4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using the correct version of Python? By installing flask_sqlalchemy and using Python3, make sure you install the module by typing `pip3 install flask-sqlalchemy`, so the module gets installed in Python3 and not another version. If you want to use Python2, make sure using the normal command `pip install flask-sqlalchemy`.